# Как в стили в JavaScript передавать переменные?

Tags: javascript

```js
let lights = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.light'))
let speedValue = 250
for (let node of lights) {
  node.style.animationDuration = `${speedValue}ms`
}
```

```html
<div className='lights'>
  <div className='light'></div>
  <div className='light'></div>
  <div className='light'></div>
  <div className='light'></div>
  <div className='light'></div>
  <div className='light'></div>
  <div className='light'></div>
</div>
```

Если в `node.style.animationDuration` напишу вручную значение, к примеру `"250ms"`,
то все прекрасно поменяется и никаких ошибок не будет. Но если менять значение с помощью
переменной (как в моем коде выше), то выдаёт ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: lights is not iterable
```

**Вопрос:** Как исправить, чтобы можно было менять значение с помощью переменной?

Comment: приведи пример, как ты меняешь значение "без помощи переменной" и у тебя все работает

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Спасибо за ответ Михаилу Комахину, но я нашел, в чем заключалась ошибка:

Я использовал `Array.from()`. Как только я убрал его и использовал стандартный

`document.querySelectorAll()`, проблема решилась и все заработало.

Comment: судя по твоему вопросу и ответу - твой код не соответствует тому, что ты привел в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

У вас всё правильно работает. Но если вы пишите не на реакте, то надо писать class для задания классов html элементов, а не className

```js
const lights = document.querySelectorAll('.light');
const speedValue = 250;

for (let i = 0; i < lights.length; i++) {
  const speed = speedValue * (i + 4);
  lights[i].style.animationDuration = `${speed}ms`;
  lights[i].textContent = `${speed}ms`;
}
```

```css
.lights {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.light {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  animation: animationScale infinite linear;
}

@keyframes animationOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animationScale {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lights">
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
  <div class="light"></div>
</div>
```